# Kafka sink to mongoDB, How do I set the "_ID" field to an existing value in one of the columns in my topic?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

I have the following topic (JSON, not AVRO) generated by Debezium

"payload": {"id": 1, "name": "test": "uuid": "f9a96ea4-3ff9-480f-bf8a-ee53a1e6e583"}

How do I set the "_ID" field (in mongo collection) to the same value "uuid"?

This is my SINK config:

```
{
    "name": "mongo-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": 3,
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "topics": "s4farm.animal",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://user:password@host:port/?authSource=database",
        "database": "database",
        "collection": "s4farm_animal",
        "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy", 
        "value.projection.list": "id",
        "value.projection.type": "whitelist",
        "writemodel.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: See this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191051/mongodb-kafka-sink-connector-doesnt-process-the-renamebyregex-processor